# Processing data I gathered. How to get the csv's to line up on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a couple of csv where there are two columns: Item and Price. Some csv's have different number of rows, some match exactly. How can I then combine the csv's so that the prices match up to the correct index name (Item) where the prices for each csv goes into it's own column (as date of csv) AND if the Item is not present in the index, it will get concatenated?
I manually added the file creation date as another column for each csv since I failed to take this into account when I generated the first batch, but I'm not sure this is actually useful since I can just set the label name as the date.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
    Item                      csv/date1  csv/date2     csv/date...
    Topper Blue Glitter1 ea    2.50        2.75         2.55
    Topper Pink Glitter1 ea    2.50        2.75         2.55
    Bamboo Needles 35MM1 ea    2.75        2.75         2.99
    6MM Knitting Needles ea                3.50
    8MM Bamboo Needles   ea                             3.79
```

EDIT

Output with concat:

```
                                        0         Date        Price
    Item            
    DoleSunflower Bacon Crunch Cho..    NaN      2020-03-16   $4.98
    Apple Slices280 g                   NaN      2020-03-16   $4.00
    PC OrganicsCooking Onions907 g      NaN      2020-03-16   $2.98
    Limes1 ea                           NaN      2020-03-16   $0.68
    Granny Smith Apples                 NaN      2020-03-16   $1.09
    ... ... ... ...
    Greenhouse Peppers, Yellow       2020-03-17   NaN          NaN
    Lettuce Iceberg1 ea              2020-03-17   NaN          NaN
    Farmer's MarketSweet Baby        2020-03-17   NaN          NaN
    Kohlrabi                         2020-03-17   NaN          NaN
    Farmer's MarketFM English Cucu   2020-03-17   NaN          NaN
```

Output with merge:

```
                                Price_x  Date_x     Price_y    Date_y
    Item                
    DoleSunflower Bacon C       $4.98   2020-03-16  NaN NaN
    Apple Slices280 g           $4.00   2020-03-16  NaN NaN
    PC OrganicsCooking On       $2.98   2020-03-16  NaN NaN
    Limes1 ea                   $0.68   2020-03-16  $0.68   2020-03-17
    Limes1 ea                   $0.68   2020-03-16  $0.68   2020-03-17
```

Finally got the desired results with concat. Suggestion below made iteration easier:

```
                                    03-16-2020  03-17-2020  03-20-2020
    Item            
    DoleSunflower Bacon Crunch      $4.98       NaN          NaN
    Apple Slices280 g               $4.00       NaN          NaN
    PC OrganicsCooking Onio         $2.98       NaN          NaN
    Limes1 ea                       $0.68       NaN          NaN
    Granny Smith Apple              $1.09       NaN          NaN
    ... ... ... ...
    Green Cabbage                   NaN         NaN          $2.52
    Celery Stalks1 ea               NaN         NaN          $1.9
```

Comment: Hey, can you please post how one of the CSV looks like?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: AMC, I can't figure out how to have the csv's line up on rows on a different column if the index is present already, and then if it isn't, to just it's index (i.e. Item) at the bottom or wherever on the Item column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read every CSV, into a different dataframe, set `item` to be the index, rename `price` column to be the `creation_date` and finally concatenate all of them, this is an example by pre-defining CSV names it might require some adjustments:

```
 csv_files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

 dfs = [pd.read_csv(x) for x in csv_files]

 for df in dfs:
      df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
      df.set_index('Item', inplace=True)
      date = df.Date.max().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
      df.rename({'Price': date}, inplace=True)

 df_final = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it throws an error while setting the date variable. Apparently, it does not exist for the file.

Comment: That makes sense because I did not know how the variables were named.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to format this... but I'm getting those errors for the Date...
----> 2      df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

        AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: One of your CSV files do not have `Date` column it was not included when reading the CSV

Comment: Make sure `dfs` is a list of data frames where each element is the dataframe of the CSV files, tris this to see if one of them is missing `Date`:   `data_colums = ['Date' in df.columns for df in dfs]` , `data_columns` should only contain `True` values

Comment: It returns the same AttributeError. Also double checked my Data columns. Unless it matter that I just manually typed in the string 'Data' on the header on the csv and dragged the creation date down. type(dfs) returns a list.

Comment: Can you please post in text-format the head of two of the dataframes you already have loaded? not images, you can use `df.head().to_clipboard()`  to copy

Comment: We might have a problem further up.. it returned the same 
        AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: That is an example, i dont know your variable names.

Comment: I found where my problem was and got the True outputs. I also got the list of lists (objects?). I would still have to merge or concat it if I want to get something similar to my edits like you said, but your suggestion makes for an easy way to read multiple csv's. I'll try to work from the suggestions so far. Thanks!

Comment: Try to set Date as index and the concat the dataframes, if that works consider in closin the question, glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create dataframes using `read_csv`, `set_index` on the Item column and you should then do a `concat` or `merge`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='outer')

df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Avoid outer join unless really required, use it only if you want to populate all the records, otherwise use an inner join.
You could also do a left or right join if you prefer it that way.
Read more here: [Merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [concat documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

It's hard to say more without looking at the data.

Comment: I'm getting errors for the concat part. Initially I thought it was because of uneven rows, but I edited the actual csv by hand, and it was still the same. Something to do with setting the axis as a column[?] since it went away after setting is as 0.


Anyway, I tried something which I included in my edit that kind of worked, now I have to figure out how to get the Prices in there.